# What, if anything, does this series involving Stirling numbers of the second kind/ordered Bell numbers converge to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions

I would like to sum the following series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{u^n}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)! S_{n+1,k}p^k,$$

where $S_{n,k}$ are [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), $0<p<1, \ 0<u<1.$  We can set $p=u,$ if that makes things easier.

I tried to attack this with generating functions, and came up with something that seems certainly wrong, but it seems like a clean closed form solution may exist.

Comment: Could you show your attempt?

Comment: Hi dimpol.  If Marko's answer below is correct, it looks like I got the generating function for S_{n+1,k} wrong.  I thought the term in front of the z^{n+1} was (n+1), not (n+1)!.  Still don't understand why it's (n+1)!, actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We seek to simplify

$$\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{u^n}{n!}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{k-1} (k-1)! {n+1\brace k} p^k.$$

Using formal power series we have

$${n+1\brace k} =
(n+1)! [z^{n+1}] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!}.$$

We obtain for the sum

$$\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{u^n}{n!} (n+1)! [z^{n+1}]
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{k-1} \frac{1}{k} (\exp(z)-1)^k p^k
\\ = \sum_{n\ge 0} u^n (n+1) [z^{n+1}]
\log\left(1+p(\exp(z)-1)\right)
\\ = \left.\log\left(1+p(\exp(z)-1)\right)'\right|_{z=u}.$$

This yields
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{p\exp(u)}{1+p(\exp(u)-1)}.}$$